# How to connect to external speaker from WebRTC

Tags: android, bluetooth, webrtc

I want to connect with external speaker which are connected with my device through bluetooth and use as an audio output when i start video call using webrtc. bluetooth speaker working fine But when i call using webrtc it only use internal speaker.

Is there any way to control which speaker i use when video call start in webrtc.

Edit: i also try to enable bluetooth as output from my android application after webrtc call start but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how it's on Android, but on a browser you cannot control from the browser the sound output channel, but rather from the OS mixer, where you can attach the application with a sound output channel.

I would think it should be the same with Android, either from OS or from SDK programatically.

Comment: I am using android crosswalk plugin to develop web application to run on android phone. It seems to be select output device from webrtc https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/ but not working on android